# Recognize Excel Pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following pattern referencing a separate sheet.

D3 has `=SUM(TUESDAY!H3:H15)`
D4 has `=SUM(TUESDAY!H18:H30)`
D5 has `=SUM(TUESDAY!H33:H45)`

this pattern will go on through column D

How do I get this repeating without manually typing each it in each cell?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in cell D3, then copy down

`=SUM(OFFSET(Tuesday!$H$1,(ROW()-3)*15+2,0,13,))`

Comment: +1 Very nice, though if you are referring to the current cell, it is probably better to just use `Row()` instead of `Row(address)`. It is less complicated and translated better to conditional formatting rules. :-)

Comment: @DanielCook: In that case, should I edit my answer, or should I let it stay with your comment?

Comment: +1 nicely handled. It's 50/50 whether you edit it, the formula works as is, and readers can view Daniel's comment.

Comment: unfortunetly i am not getting it to work correctly. when i paste this formula in D3 through to D30. Every cell has the same total from Sheet "TUESDAY! H3:H18"

Comment: Same thing if you replace row(d3) by row()?

Comment: Edited answer to reflect adjustment.